# How to improve FDM solver for unsteady viscous flow?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, finite-difference-method, fluid-dynamics

To solve the problem that is discussed in the [paper Finite Difference Analysis of Time-Dependent Viscous Nanofluid Flow Between Parallel Plates](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0253-6102/71/11/1293) we developed FDM solver based on the code from the [blog Using Mathematica to Simulate and Visualize Fluid Flow in a Box](https://blog.wolfram.com/2013/07/09/using-mathematica-to-simulate-and-visualize-fluid-flow-in-a-box/). To check the results obtained, we simultaneously used FEM solver published [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180959/solver-for-unsteady-flow-with-the-use-of-the-navier-stokes-and-mathematica-fem).  The problem we want to discuss is that FEM solver is 10 times faster than FDM solver. Whereas we expected that there would be an inverse relationship. Since we asked before, why is FEM solver so slow? Let's compare the 2 methods FEM and FDM, and the results. The problem we want to solve is shown in the Figure 1 below
[image: Figure 1]

**1. FDM solver.** So we see that in the equations for flow there is no pressure although the equation of continuity must be satisfied. Therefore we add to the left part of the second and third equation $\nabla_xP,\nabla_yP$ respectively with initial condition $p(0,\xi ,\eta)=0$ and boundary condition $p(\tau,l_b,\eta)=0$, where $l_b=5$, and $0\le \tau \le 1,0 \le \xi \le l_b, 0 \le \eta \le 1$. Also below we us $t, x, y$ instead of $\tau, \xi, \eta$.
First 3 equations can be solved separately as follows

```
XYgrid[dom_List, pts_List] := 
  MapThread[
   N@Range[Sequence @@ #1, Abs[Subtract @@ #1]/#2] &, {dom, 
    pts - 1}];
BoundaryIndex[xgridlen_, ygridlen_] := 
  Module[{tmp, left, right, bot, top}, 
   tmp = Table[(n - 1) ygridlen + Range[1, ygridlen], {n, 1, 
      xgridlen}]; {left, right} = tmp[[{1, -1}]]; {bot, top} = 
    Transpose[{First[#], Last[#]} & /@ tmp]; {top, right[[2 ;; -2]], 
    bot, left[[2 ;; -2]]}];
Attributes[MakeVariables] = {Listable};
MakeVariables[var_, n_] := Table[Unique[var], {n}];
FDMat[deriv_, xygrid_, difforder_] := 
 Map[NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[#, xygrid, 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> difforder]["DifferentiationMatrix"] &, deriv]
{dt, tmax, domain, pts, difforder, Rey, H1, c1, M1, b1} = {1/20, 
   20, {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}, {50, 10}, 4, 1., .1, .5, 5, 3};
xygrid = XYgrid[domain, pts]; {nx, ny} = 
 Map[Length, xygrid]; {top, right, bot, left} = 
 BoundaryIndex[nx, ny]; {dx, dy, dx2, dy2} = 
 FDMat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 2}}, xygrid, difforder]; {dx1, 
  dy1} = FDMat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, xygrid, 1]; {uvar, vvar, pvar} = 
 MakeVariables[{u, v, p}, nx ny]; {uvar0, vvar0, pvar0} = 
 Array[#, nx ny] & /@ {u0, v0, p0}; eqnu = (uvar - uvar0)/dt + 
  uvar0 (dx . uvar) + vvar0 (dy . uvar) + dx1 . pvar - 
  1/Rey (dx2 + dy2) . 
    uvar + (H1 + c1)/(1/M1) uvar; eqnv = (vvar - vvar0)/dt + 
  uvar0 (dx . vvar) + vvar0 (dy . vvar) + dy1 . pvar - 
  1/Rey (dx2 + dy2) . vvar + c1/(1/M1) vvar;
eqncont = dx . uvar + dy . vvar; boundaries = 
 Join[top, right, bot, left]; sgrid = 
 Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ xygrid], 1]; 
eqnu[[boundaries]] = uvar[[boundaries]]; 
eqnu[[bot]] = uvar[[bot]] - M1 sgrid[[bot]][[All, 1]]; 
eqnu[[right]] = (dx . uvar)[[right]]; 
eqnv[[boundaries]] = vvar[[boundaries]]; 
eqnv[[bot]] = vvar[[bot]] - b1; eqnv[[right]] = (dx . vvar)[[right]]; 
eqncont[[right]] = 
 pvar[[right]]; {deqns, dvars} = {Join[eqnu, eqnv, eqncont], 
  Join[uvar, vvar, pvar]};

rule[0] = 
 Join[Table[uvar0[[i]] -> 0, {i, Length[uvar0]}], 
  Table[vvar0[[i]] -> 0, {i, Length[vvar0]}]]; dvar0 = 
 Table[1/10, Length[dvars]];
Do[sol[j] = 
    Quiet@FindRoot[deqns /. rule[j - 1], 
      Table[{dvars[[i]], dvar0[[i]]}, {i, Length[dvars]}], 
      Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"}]; 
   dvar0 = dvars /. sol[j]; 
   rule[j] = 
    Join[Table[uvar0[[i]] -> dvar0[[i]], {i, Length[uvar0]}], 
     Table[vvar0[[i]] -> dvar0[[i + Length[uvar0]]], {i, 1, 
       Length[vvar0]}]];, {j, tmax}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

On my notebook with 9th gen Intel core 7 it takes 291.367 s. Visualization

```
{u, v, p} = 
  Map[Interpolation@Join[sgrid, Transpose@List@#, 2] &, 
   Partition[dvars /. sol[tmax], Length[sgrid]]];
{ContourPlot[u[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  Contours -> 20, PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotLabel -> "u", 
 FrameLabel -> Automatic],

ContourPlot[v[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  Contours -> 20, PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotLabel -> "v", FrameLabel -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

**2. FEM solver.**

```
UX[0][x_, y_] := 0; 
VY[0][x_, y_] := 0; 
P0[0][x_, y_] := 0; 
AbsoluteTiming[
  Do[{UX[i], VY[i], P0[i]} = NDSolveValue[{{Inactive[Div][{{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}} . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
           Derivative[1, 0][p][x, y] + ((H1 + c1)/(1/M1))*u[x, y] + (u[x, y] - UX[i - 1][x, y])/dt + UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[u[x, y], x] + 
           VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[u[x, y], y], Inactive[Div][{{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}} . Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
           Derivative[0, 1][p][x, y] + (c1/(1/M1))*v[x, y] + (v[x, y] - VY[i - 1][x, y])/dt + UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[v[x, y], x] + 
           VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[v[x, y], y], Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y] + Derivative[0, 1][v][x, y]} == {0, 0, 0} /. 
        {\[Mu] -> 1, M1 -> 5, H1 -> 0.1, c1 -> 0.5, dt -> 1/20}, {DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, x == 0 && y > 0], 
         DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == M1*x, v[x, y] == b1}, y == 0 && x > 0.], DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, y == L], 
         DirichletCondition[{p[x, y] == 0}, x == lb]} /. {L -> 1, lb -> 5, M1 -> 5, b1 -> 3, dt -> 1/20}}, {u, v, p}, 
      Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {5, 1}]], Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}, 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0025}}], {i, 1, 20}]; ]
```

On my notebook it takes 16.4886 s. Visualization

```
{ContourPlot[UX[20][x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  Contours -> 20, PlotLabel -> "u", FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, ContourStyle -> Yellow],
  ContourPlot[VY[20][x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  Contours -> 20, PlotLabel -> "v", FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, ContourStyle -> Yellow]}
```

[image: Figure 3]

Therefore, with the same results FEM solver 17-18 times faster than FDM solver. Now we need to make parametric research, for example, compute the Nusselt number $Nu_x=-x(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y})$ as a function of $Pr, Nb$ with a given flow. For this we organize `Module` as follows

**1 FDM solver.**

```
Nu[Pr_, Nb_, x0_, y0_] := 
  Module[{Sc1 = 0.5, Nt1 = 0.5}, {dx, dy, dx2, dy2} = 
    FDMat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 2}}, xygrid, 2]; {Tvar, 
     phivar} = 
    MakeVariables[{\[Theta], \[Phi]}, nx ny]; {Tvar0, phivar0} = 
    Array[#, nx ny] & /@ {T0, phi0}; 
   eqnT = (Tvar - Tvar0)/dt + uvar0 (dx . Tvar) + vvar0 (dy . Tvar) - 
     1/Pr (dx2 + dy2) . Tvar - 
     Nt1 ((dx . Tvar) (dx . Tvar0) + (dy . Tvar) (dy . Tvar0)) - 
     Nb ((dx . Tvar) (dx . phivar0) + (dy . Tvar) (dy . phivar0)); 
   eqnphi = (phivar - phivar0)/dt + uvar0 (dx . phivar) + 
     vvar0 (dy . phivar) - 1/Sc1 (dx2 + dy2) . phivar - 
     Nt1/(Nb*Sc1) (dx2 + dy2) . Tvar;
   eqnT[[boundaries]] = Tvar[[boundaries]]; 
   eqnT[[bot]] = Tvar[[bot]] - 1; 
   eqnT[[right]] = (dx . Tvar)[[right]]; 
   eqnT[[left]] = (dx . Tvar)[[left]]; 
   eqnphi[[boundaries]] = phivar[[boundaries]]; 
   eqnphi[[bot]] = phivar[[bot]] - 1; 
   eqnphi[[right]] = (dx . phivar)[[right]]; 
   eqnphi[[left]] = (dx . phivar)[[left]]; {deqns1, 
     dvars1} = {Join[eqnT, eqnphi], Join[Tvar, phivar]};
   rule1[0] = 
    Join[rule[0], Table[Tvar0[[i]] -> 0, {i, Length[Tvar0]}], 
     Table[phivar0[[i]] -> 0, {i, Length[phivar0]}]]; 
   dvar01 = Table[1/10, Length[dvars1]];
   Do[sol1[j] = 
     Quiet@FindRoot[deqns1 /. rule1[j - 1], 
       Table[{dvars1[[i]], dvar01[[i]]}, {i, Length[dvars1]}]]; 
    dvar01 = dvars1 /. sol1[j]; 
    rule1[j] = 
     Join[rule[j], 
      Table[Tvar0[[i]] -> dvar01[[i]], {i, Length[Tvar0]}], 
      Table[phivar0[[i]] -> dvar01[[i + Length[Tvar0]]], {i, 1, 
        Length[phivar0]}]];, {j, tmax}]; {T, phi} = 
    Map[Interpolation@Join[sgrid, Transpose@List@#, 2] &, 
     Partition[dvars1 /. sol1[tmax], 
      Length[sgrid]]]; -x0 (Derivative[1, 0][T][x0, y0] + 
      Derivative[0, 1][T][x0, y0])];
```

We test this code in one point

```
Nu[1, .5, 1, 0] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {117.234, 0.225568}
```

**2 FEM solver.**

```
mesh = UX[20]["ElementMesh"]
Nu[Pr1_, Nb1_, x0_, y0_] := 
  Module[{Sc1 = 0.5, Nt1 = 0.5}, T0[0][x_, y_] := 0;
   Phi[0][x_, y_] := 0;
   Do[
    {T0[i], Phi[i]} = 
      NDSolveValue[{{Inactive[
              Div][({{-\[Mu]1, 0}, {0, -\[Mu]1}} . 
               Inactive[Grad][T[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
              y}] + (T[x, y] - T0[i - 1][x, y])/dt + 
            UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[T[x, y], x] + 
            VY[i - 1][x, y]*
             D[T[x, y], 
              y] - (Nb1*(D[T[x, y], x]*D[Phi[i - 1][x, y], x] + 
                 D[T[x, y], y]*D[Phi[i - 1][x, y], y]) + 
              Nt1*((D[T0[i - 1][x, y], x])^2 + (D[T0[i - 1][x, y], 
                    y])^2)), 
           Inactive[
              Div][({{-\[Mu]2, 0}, {0, -\[Mu]2}} . 
               Inactive[Grad][phi[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + 
            Inactive[
              Div][({{-\[Mu]3, 0}, {0, -\[Mu]3}} . 
               Inactive[Grad][T[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
              y}] + (phi[x, y] - Phi[i - 1][x, y])/dt + 
            UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[phi[x, y], x] + 
            VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[phi[x, y], y]} == {0, 0} /. {\[Mu]1 -> 
           1/Pr1, \[Mu]2 -> 1/Sc1, \[Mu]3 -> Nt1/(Nb1*Sc1), 
          dt -> 1/20}, {DirichletCondition[{T[x, y] == 0, 
            phi[x, y] == 0}, y == L && x > 0], 
          DirichletCondition[{T[x, y] == 1 , phi[x, y] == 1}, 
           y == 0 && x > 0.]
          } /. {L -> 1, lb -> 5}}, {T, phi}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
       Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
         "InterpolationOrder" -> {T -> 2, phi -> 2}}];, {i, 1, 
     20}]; -x0 (Derivative[1, 0][T0[20]][x0, y0] + 
      Derivative[0, 1][T0[20]][x0, y0])];
```

Test in one point

```
Nu[1, .5, 1, 0] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {13.8536, 0.229032}
```

Therefore, we see that the FEM solver is 8-18 times faster than the FDM solver. And this is very strange, since it seems that FDM should be faster than FEM.

**Update 1.** We can reduce the integration time by a factor of 6-7 using `LeastSquares` instead of `FinfRoot` in FDM code as follows

```
XYgrid[dom_List, pts_List] := 
  MapThread[
   N@Range[Sequence @@ #1, Abs[Subtract @@ #1]/#2] &, {dom, 
    pts - 1}];
BoundaryIndex[xgridlen_, ygridlen_] := 
  Module[{tmp, left, right, bot, top}, 
   tmp = Table[(n - 1) ygridlen + Range[1, ygridlen], {n, 1, 
      xgridlen}]; {left, right} = tmp[[{1, -1}]]; {bot, top} = 
    Transpose[{First[#], Last[#]} & /@ tmp]; {top, right[[2 ;; -2]], 
    bot, left[[2 ;; -2]]}];
Attributes[MakeVariables] = {Listable};
MakeVariables[var_, n_] := Table[Unique[var], {n}];
FDMat[deriv_, xygrid_, difforder_] := 
 Map[NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[#, xygrid, 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> difforder]["DifferentiationMatrix"] &, deriv]
{dt, tmax, domain, pts, difforder, Rey, H1, c1, M1, b1} = {1/20, 
   20, {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}, {50, 10}, 4, 1., .1, .5, 5, 3};
xygrid = XYgrid[domain, pts]; {nx, ny} = 
 Map[Length, xygrid]; {top, right, bot, left} = 
 BoundaryIndex[nx, ny]; {dx, dy, dx2, dy2} = 
 FDMat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 2}}, xygrid, difforder]; {dx1, 
  dy1} = FDMat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, xygrid, 1]; {uvar, vvar, pvar} = 
 MakeVariables[{u, v, p}, nx ny]; {uvar0, vvar0, pvar0} = 
 Array[#, nx ny] & /@ {u0, v0, p0}; eqnu = (uvar - uvar0)/dt + 
  uvar0 (dx . uvar) + vvar0 (dy . uvar) + dx1 . pvar - 
  1/Rey (dx2 + dy2) . 
    uvar + (H1 + c1)/(1/M1) uvar; eqnv = (vvar - vvar0)/dt + 
  uvar0 (dx . vvar) + vvar0 (dy . vvar) + dy1 . pvar - 
  1/Rey (dx2 + dy2) . vvar + c1/(1/M1) vvar;
eqncont = dx . uvar + dy . vvar; boundaries = 
 Join[top, right, bot, left]; sgrid = 
 Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ xygrid], 1]; 
eqnu[[boundaries]] = uvar[[boundaries]]; 
eqnu[[bot]] = uvar[[bot]] - M1 sgrid[[bot]][[All, 1]]; 
eqnu[[right]] = (dx . uvar)[[right]]; 
eqnv[[boundaries]] = vvar[[boundaries]]; 
eqnv[[bot]] = vvar[[bot]] - b1; eqnv[[bot[[1]]]] = vvar[[bot[[1]]]]; 
eqnv[[right]] = (dx . vvar)[[right]]; 
eqncont[[right]] = 
 pvar[[right]]; {deqns, dvars} = {Join[eqnu, eqnv, eqncont], 
  Join[uvar, vvar, pvar]};

 rule[0] = 
  Join[Table[uvar0[[i]] -> 0, {i, Length[uvar0]}], 
   Table[vvar0[[i]] -> 0, {i, Length[vvar0]}]];
Do[{vec, mat} = CoefficientArrays[deqns /. rule[j - 1], dvars]; 
   sol[j] = LeastSquares[mat, -vec, Method -> "Direct"]; 
   dvar0 = sol[j]; 
   rule[j] = 
    Join[Table[uvar0[[i]] -> dvar0[[i]], {i, Length[uvar0]}], 
     Table[vvar0[[i]] -> dvar0[[i + Length[uvar0]]], {i, 1, 
       Length[vvar0]}]];, {j, tmax}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*Out[]= {45.9387, Null}*)
```

**Update 2** We can reduce computation time in a case of FEM code using [ramp function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#643148355) described in tutorials as follows

```
rules = {length -> 5, height -> 1, M1 -> 5, b1 -> 3, H1 -> 0.1, 
   c1 -> .5, \[Mu] -> 1, \[Rho] -> 1};
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, height}] /. rules;
region = RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega], AspectRatio -> Automatic]

ClearAll[op, ic, bcs, \[Rho], \[Mu]]
op = {\[Rho]*D[u[t, x, y], t] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}} . 
      Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
     y}] + \[Rho]*{{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}} . 
     Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
   D[p[t, x, y], x], \[Rho]*D[v[t, x, y], t] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}} . 
      Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
     y}] + \[Rho]*{{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}} . 
     Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}] + D[p[t, x, y], y], 
  D[u[t, x, y], x] + D[v[t, x, y], y]}; source = {(c1 + H1)*M1*
   u[t, x, y], c1*M1*v[t, x, y], 0};
rampFunction[min_, max_, c_, r_] := 
 Function[t, (min*Exp[c*r] + max*Exp[r*t])/(Exp[c*r] + Exp[r*t])]
sf = rampFunction[0, 1, 4, 5]; ic = {u[-1, x, y] == 0, 
  v[-1, x, y] == 0, 
  p[-1, x, y] == 
   0}; bcs = {DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, 
    x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == sf[10 t + 5] M1 x, 
     v[t, x, y] == sf[10 t + 5] b1}, y == 0 && 0 < x < length], 
   DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, 
    y == height && 0 <= x < length], 
   DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0., x == length]} /. rules;
AbsoluteTiming[{xVel, yVel, pressure} = 
   NDSolveValue[{op + source == {0, 0, 0} /. rules, bcs, ic}, {u, v, 
     p}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {t, -1, 1}, 
    Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"IDA", 
        "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 2}, 
      "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> True, 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
          "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}, 
          "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}}];]
```

In this case we have `Out[]= {6.50973, Null}`. But there is the problem with this approach since computation time for the Nusselt number increases 100 times compare to function `Nu[]` for FEM introduced above. Really, we have

```
mesh = xVel["ElementMesh"]

ClearAll[ic1, op1, bc1, T, phi]

ic1 = {T[-1, x, y] == 0,
  phi[-1, x, y] == 
   0}; op1 = {Inactive[
     Div][({{-\[Mu]1, 0}, {0, -\[Mu]1}} . 
      Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + 
   D[T[t, x, y], t] + {{xVel[t, x, y], yVel[t, x, y]}} . 
    Inactive[Grad][
     T[t, x, y], {x, 
      y}] - (Nb1*(Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}] . 
        Inactive[Grad][phi[t, x, y], {x, y}]) + 
     Nt1*(Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}] . 
        Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}])), 
  Inactive[
     Div][({{-\[Mu]2, 0}, {0, -\[Mu]2}} . 
      Inactive[Grad][phi[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][({{-\[Mu]3, 0}, {0, -\[Mu]3}} . 
      Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + 
   D[phi[t, x, y], t] + {{xVel[t, x, y], yVel[t, x, y]}} . 
    Inactive[Grad][
     phi[t, x, y], {x, y}]}; bc1 = {DirichletCondition[{T[t, x, y] == 
     0, phi[t, x, y] == 0}, y == height && x > 0], 
  DirichletCondition[{T[t, x, y] == sf[10 t + 5], 
    phi[t, x, y] == sf[10 t + 5]}, y == 0 && x > 0.]};


Dynamic["time: " <> ToString[CForm[currentTime]]]
AbsoluteTiming[{T0, Phi} = 
   NDSolveValue[{Flatten[Activate[op1]] == {0, 0} /. {\[Mu]1 -> 
          1/Pr1, \[Mu]2 -> 1/Sc1, \[Mu]3 -> Nt1/(Nb1*Sc1)} /. 
       rules /. {Sc1 -> 0.5, Nt1 -> 0.5, Pr1 -> 1, Nb1 -> .5}, 
     bc1 /. rules, ic1}, {T, phi}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, {t, -1, 1},
     Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"IDA", 
        "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 2}, 
      "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> True, 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
          "InterpolationOrder" -> {T -> 2, phi -> 2}}}}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = t;)];]
```

It takes about 2000s on my laptop, nevertheless it gives the Nusselt number `Nu=-(Derivative[0, 1, 0][T0][1, 1, 0] + Derivative[0, 0, 1][T0][1, 1, 0])` of about 0.228415, while with FDM we compute `Nu[1, .5, 1, 0]=0.225568`, and with linear FEM of about 0.229032.

Comment: @ Alex Trounev: How long does each FindRoot take in your  FDM Code?

Comment: @ Alex Trounev: On my machine each iteration takes about 15s to converge. With Method->"ConjugateGradient" this is down to 4s for each iteration.

Comment: @wvt_beginner Thank you very much for your help. With option  `Method->"ConjugateGradient"` we have on every step `FindRoot::bdmtd: Value of option Method -> ConjugateGradient is not Automatic, Brent, Secant, AffineCovariantNewton or Newton.`

Comment: :I'm on version 13.3 here. What version are you using?

Comment: I also tried your visualisation, but u[x,y] and v[x,y] seem to undefiened in your code.

Comment: @wvt_beginner Yes, you are right, please add interpolation code before plot `{u, v, p} = Map[Interpolation@Join[sgrid, Transpose@List@#, 2] &, 
   Partition[dvars /. sol[tmax], Length[sgrid]]];`. I have "13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)"

Comment: thanks for the update. I have to admit I was mistaken by the manual when trying to use the method of conjugate gradients, removing Quiet@ showed this. Anyway the resulting set of equations seems to be an ill conditioned problem. Is there a fast way to extract the coefficient matrix in order to use LinearSolve?

Comment: I was able to extract the coefficients with CoefficientArrays. The coefficient matrix is singular for all iterative steps in your FDM Code. Also When plotting the pressure, the pressure field looks suspicious. Your first FEM code doesn*t even run here.

Comment: @wvt_beginner You are right, matrix is singular, it is why we use option `Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"}` deigned for this case. Also FEM code run, but you probably can't copy it properly. I upload code in the Raw InputForm.  Try again.

Comment: I haven't looked into the code yet, but if I understand it correctly, you've coded a primary solver yourself for `t` direction? This may be the root of the problem, because ODE/DAE solver (esp. the ODE IVP solver) of `NDSolve` is optimized.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, this is implicit difference scheme with linear system of equations on every step. The main problem is that `LinearSolve` can't solve this system due to matrix singularity. It is why we use `FindRoot` with option  `Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"`.  In a case of FEM this system solved on every step as it is and faster than that with FDM.

Comment: @Alex Trounev: As an engineer I am always cautious when singular or near singular system matrices occur. Though I am not an expert in CFD, I would like to ask why near singularity occurs here. For completeness: There seems to be an undocumented option for LinearSolve: [link]https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182008/arbitrary-precision-nearly-singular-matrices-and-linearsolve[\link]

Comment: @wvt_beginner It is not clear why matrix is singular in FDM code, but maybe it connects with the boundary conditions for `u, v` which are not zero at t>0, while initial conditions set to be zero at t=0. Note, that this is the main reason why we use an implicit difference scheme.

Comment: In your question you write: "Since we asked before, why is FEM solver so slow". Is this a typo and you mean the FDM solver?

Comment: Actually FEM solver for unsteady flow is slow too, so it could be very good solution if you can improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since my post is too long I would like to answer my question rather then update it. First, I developed new code based on explicit difference scheme with projection step instead of direct pressure computation. Therefore we use on every time step the equations $\nabla^2P=\nabla.\vec{v}, \vec{v}=\vec{v}-\nabla P$ instead of continuity equation $\nabla. \vec{v}=0$. As result we decrease computation time for FDM code from 291.367 s to 20.6789s that practically is the same as with FEM code (16.4886 s). We have

```
XYgrid[dom_List, pts_List] := 
  MapThread[
   N@Range[Sequence @@ #1, Abs[Subtract @@ #1]/#2] &, {dom, 
    pts - 1}];
BoundaryIndex[xgridlen_, ygridlen_] := 
  Module[{tmp, left, right, bot, top, left1, right1}, 
   tmp = Table[(n - 1) ygridlen + Range[1, ygridlen], {n, 1, 
      xgridlen}]; {left, right} = tmp[[{1, -1}]]; {left1, right1} = 
    tmp[[{2, -2}]]; {bot, top} = 
    Transpose[{First[#], Last[#]} & /@ tmp]; {top, right[[2 ;; -2]], 
    bot, left[[2 ;; -2]], right1[[2 ;; -2]], left1[[2 ;; -2]]}];
Attributes[MakeVariables] = {Listable};
MakeVariables[var_, n_] := Table[Unique[var], {n}];
FDMat[deriv_, xygrid_, difforder_] := 
 Map[NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[#, xygrid, 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> difforder]["DifferentiationMatrix"] &, deriv]
{dt, tmax, domain, pts, difforder, Rey, H1, c1, M1, b1} = {1/1000, 
   1000, {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}, {50, 10}, 4, 1., .1, .5, 5, 3};
xygrid = XYgrid[domain, pts]; {nx, ny} = 
 Map[Length, xygrid]; {top, right, bot, left, right1, left1} = 
 BoundaryIndex[nx, ny]; {dx, dy, dx2, dy2} = 
 FDMat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 2}}, xygrid, difforder]; {dx1, 
  dy1} = FDMat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, xygrid, 1]; {uvar0, vvar0, pvar0} = 
 Table[ConstantArray[0, {nx ny, tmax}], {3}]; boundaries = 
 Join[top, right, bot, left]; sgrid = 
 Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ xygrid], 1]; {pvar} = 
 MakeVariables[{pp}, nx ny];

Do[{uvar, vvar} = {uvar0[[All, i]], vvar0[[All, i]]}; 
   eqnu = uvar (dx . uvar) + vvar (dy . uvar) - 
     1/Rey (dx2 + dy2) . uvar + (H1 + c1)/(1/M1) uvar; 
   eqnv = uvar (dx . vvar) + vvar (dy . vvar) - 
     1/Rey (dx2 + dy2) . vvar + c1/(1/M1) vvar;
   uvar0[[All, i + 1]] = uvar0[[All, i]] - dt eqnu; 
   vvar0[[All, i + 1]] = vvar0[[All, i]] - dt eqnv; 
   uvar0[[top, i + 1]] = uvar0[[top, 1]]; 
   uvar0[[left, i + 1]] = uvar0[[left, 1]]; 
   uvar0[[bot, i + 1]] = M1 sgrid[[bot]][[All, 1]]; 
   vvar0[[bot, i + 1]] = b1; vvar0[[top, i + 1]] = vvar0[[top, 1]]; 
   vvar0[[left, i + 1]] = vvar0[[left, 1]]; 
   eqnp = (dx2 + dy2) . pvar - dx . uvar0[[All, i + 1]] - 
     dy . vvar0[[All, i + 1]]; eqnp[[right]] = pvar[[right]]; 
   eqnp[[left]] = (dx . pvar)[[left]]; 
   eqnp[[top]] = (dy . pvar)[[top]]; 
   eqnp[[bot]] = (dy . pvar)[[bot]]; {vec, mat} = 
    CoefficientArrays[eqnp, pvar]; 
   sol = LinearSolve[mat, -vec, Method -> "Krylov"]; 
   uvar0[[All, i + 1]] = uvar0[[All, i + 1]] - dx . sol; 
   vvar0[[All, i + 1]] = vvar0[[All, i + 1]] - dy . sol; 
   uvar0[[top, i + 1]] = uvar0[[top, 1]]; 
   uvar0[[left, i + 1]] = uvar0[[left, 1]]; 
   uvar0[[bot, i + 1]] = M1 sgrid[[bot]][[All, 1]]; 
   vvar0[[bot, i + 1]] = b1; vvar0[[top, i + 1]] = vvar0[[top, 1]]; 
   vvar0[[left, i + 1]] = vvar0[[left, 1]], {i, 1, 
    tmax - 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Visualization

```
{u, v, p} = 
  Map[Interpolation@Join[sgrid, Transpose@List@#, 2] &, 
   Partition[Join[uvar0[[All, tmax]], vvar0[[All, tmax]], sol], 
    Length[sgrid]]];

{ContourPlot[u[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotLabel -> "u", 
  FrameLabel -> Automatic], 
 ContourPlot[v[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "v"], 
 ContourPlot[p[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "p"]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

We can compare velocity computed above (dashed lines) with FEM (solid lines) in different sections at `t=1`
[image: Figure 2]

Using velocity we can compute the Nusselt number as follows

```
Nu[Pr_, Nb_, x0_, y0_] := 
  Module[{Sc1 = 0.5, Nt1 = 0.5}, {dx, dy, dx2, dy2} = 
    FDMat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 2}}, xygrid, 4]; {Tvar, 
     phivar} = Table[ConstantArray[0, {nx ny, tmax}], {2}]; 
   Do[eqnT = 
     uvar0[[All, i]] (dx . Tvar[[All, i]]) + 
      vvar0[[All, i]] (dy . Tvar[[All, i]]) - 
      1/Pr (dx2 + dy2) . Tvar[[All, i]] - 
      Nt1 ((dx . Tvar[[All, i]]) (dx . Tvar[[All, i]]) + (dy . 
            Tvar[[All, i]]) (dy . Tvar[[All, i]])) - 
      Nb ((dx . Tvar[[All, i]]) (dx . phivar[[All, i]]) + (dy . 
            Tvar[[All, i]]) (dy . phivar[[All, i]])); 
    eqnphi = 
     uvar0[[All, i]] (dx . phivar[[All, i]]) + 
      vvar0[[All, i]] (dy . phivar[[All, i]]) - 
      1/Sc1 (dx2 + dy2) . phivar[[All, i]] - 
      Nt1/(Nb*Sc1) (dx2 + dy2) . Tvar[[All, i]];
    
    Tvar[[All, i + 1]] = Tvar[[All, i]] - dt eqnT; 
    phivar[[All, i + 1]] = phivar[[All, i]] - dt eqnphi; 
    Tvar[[left, i + 1]] = Tvar[[left1, i + 1]]; 
    phivar[[left, i + 1]] = phivar[[left1, i + 1]];
    Tvar[[top, i + 1]] = 0; Tvar[[bot, i + 1]] = 1; 
    phivar[[bot, i + 1]] = 1; 
    phivar[[top, i + 1]] = 0;, {i, tmax - 1}]; {T, phi} = 
    Map[Interpolation@Join[sgrid, Transpose@List@#, 2] &, 
     Partition[Join[Tvar[[All, tmax]], phivar[[All, tmax]]], 
      Length[sgrid]]]; -x0 (Derivative[1, 0][T][x0, y0] + 
      Derivative[0, 1][T][x0, y0])];
```

Test example

```
Nu[1, .5, 1, 0] // AbsoluteTiming

(*Out[]= {3.17558, 0.22788}*)
```

Note, that with implicit FDM code we have `{117.234, 0.225568}`, and with FEM solver we have `{13.8536, 0.229032}`. Therefore this FDM code for `Nu` even faster then FEM. Also now we can compile last code for `Nu`.
**Update 1** We can decrease computation time by using mixed explicit-implicit algorithm as follows

```
XYgrid[dom_List, pts_List] := 
  MapThread[
   N@Range[Sequence @@ #1, Abs[Subtract @@ #1]/#2] &, {dom, 
    pts - 1}];
BoundaryIndex[xgridlen_, ygridlen_] := 
  Module[{tmp, left, right, bot, top, left1, right1}, 
   tmp = Table[(n - 1) ygridlen + Range[1, ygridlen], {n, 1, 
      xgridlen}]; {left, right} = tmp[[{1, -1}]]; {left1, right1} = 
    tmp[[{2, -2}]]; {bot, top} = 
    Transpose[{First[#], Last[#]} & /@ tmp]; {top, right[[2 ;; -2]], 
    bot, left[[2 ;; -2]], right1[[2 ;; -2]], left1[[2 ;; -2]]}];
Attributes[MakeVariables] = {Listable};
MakeVariables[var_, n_] := Table[Unique[var], {n}];
FDMat[deriv_, xygrid_, difforder_] := 
 Map[NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[#, xygrid, 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> difforder]["DifferentiationMatrix"] &, deriv]
{dt, tmax, domain, pts, difforder, Rey, H1, c1, M1, b1} = {1/300, 
   300, {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}, {50, 10}, 2, 1., .1, .5, 5, 3};
xygrid = XYgrid[domain, pts]; {nx, ny} = 
 Map[Length, xygrid]; {top, right, bot, left, right1, left1} = 
 BoundaryIndex[nx, ny]; {dx, dy, dx2, dy2} = 
 FDMat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 2}}, xygrid, difforder]; {dx1, 
  dy1} = FDMat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, xygrid, 1]; {uvar0, vvar0, pvar0} = 
 Table[ConstantArray[0, {nx ny, tmax}], {3}]; boundaries = 
 Join[top, right, bot, left]; sgrid = 
 Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ xygrid], 1]; {pvar} = 
 MakeVariables[{pp}, nx ny];

matdt1 = IdentityMatrix[nx ny] - dt/Rey (dx2 + dy2); invdt1 = 
 Inverse[matdt1];

Do[{uvar, vvar} = {uvar0[[All, i]], vvar0[[All, i]]}; 
   eqnu = uvar (dx . uvar) + vvar (dy . uvar) + (H1 + c1)/(1/M1) uvar;
    eqnv = uvar (dx . vvar) + vvar (dy . vvar) + (c1)/(1/M1) vvar;
   uvar0[[All, i + 1]] = invdt1 . (uvar0[[All, i]] - dt eqnu); 
   vvar0[[All, i + 1]] = invdt1 . (vvar0[[All, i]] - dt eqnv); 
   uvar0[[top, i + 1]] = uvar0[[top, 1]]; 
   uvar0[[left, i + 1]] = uvar0[[left, 1]]; 
   uvar0[[bot, i + 1]] = M1 sgrid[[bot]][[All, 1]]; 
   vvar0[[bot, i + 1]] = b1; vvar0[[top, i + 1]] = vvar0[[top, 1]]; 
   vvar0[[left, i + 1]] = vvar0[[left, 1]]; 
   eqnp = (dx2 + dy2) . pvar - dx . uvar0[[All, i + 1]] - 
     dy . vvar0[[All, i + 1]]; eqnp[[right]] = pvar[[right]]; 
   eqnp[[left]] = (dx . pvar)[[left]]; 
   eqnp[[top]] = (dy . pvar)[[top]]; 
   eqnp[[bot]] = (dy . pvar)[[bot]]; {vec, mat} = 
    CoefficientArrays[eqnp, pvar]; 
   sol = LinearSolve[mat, -vec, Method -> "Banded"]; 
   uvar0[[All, i + 1]] = uvar0[[All, i + 1]] - dx . sol; 
   vvar0[[All, i + 1]] = vvar0[[All, i + 1]] - dy . sol; 
   uvar0[[top, i + 1]] = uvar0[[top, 1]]; 
   uvar0[[left, i + 1]] = uvar0[[left, 1]]; 
   uvar0[[bot, i + 1]] = M1 sgrid[[bot]][[All, 1]]; 
   vvar0[[bot, i + 1]] = b1; vvar0[[top, i + 1]] = vvar0[[top, 1]]; 
   vvar0[[left, i + 1]] = vvar0[[left, 1]], {i, 1, 
    tmax - 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

This FDM code takes 3s only, that 100 times less then FDM code with implicit algorithm. This velocity field we compare with FEM solution

```
{u, v, p} = 
  Map[Interpolation@Join[sgrid, Transpose@List@#, 2] &, 
   Partition[Join[uvar0[[All, tmax]], vvar0[[All, tmax]], sol], 
    Length[sgrid]]];

{ContourPlot[u[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotLabel -> "u", 
  FrameLabel -> Automatic], 
 ContourPlot[v[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "v"], 
 ContourPlot[p[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "p"]}
```

[image: Figure 3]

[image: Figure 4]

Also we can compute the Nusselt number as follows

```
cu0 = Max[Flatten[dx2 + dy2]]/Rey;

Nu[Pr_, Nb_, x0_, y0_] := 
  Module[{Sc1 = 0.5, Nt1 = 0.5}, {dx, dy, dx2, dy2} = 
    FDMat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 2}}, xygrid, 2]; 
   cu1 = Max[Flatten[dx2 + dy2]]; 
   cu = cu1 Max[{1/Pr, 1/Sc1, Nt1/(Nb*Sc1)}]; dt1 = .7 dt cu0/cu; 
   tmax1 = Round[tmax dt/dt1]; {Tvar, phivar} = 
    Table[ConstantArray[0, {nx ny, tmax1}], {2}];
   Do[i1 = Round[i dt1/dt]; 
    eqnT = uvar0[[All, i1]] (dx . Tvar[[All, i]]) + 
      vvar0[[All, i1]] (dy . Tvar[[All, i]]) - 
      1/Pr (dx2 + dy2) . Tvar[[All, i]] - 
      Nt1 ((dx . Tvar[[All, i]]) (dx . Tvar[[All, i]]) + (dy . 
            Tvar[[All, i]]) (dy . Tvar[[All, i]])) - 
      Nb ((dx . Tvar[[All, i]]) (dx . phivar[[All, i]]) + (dy . 
            Tvar[[All, i]]) (dy . phivar[[All, i]]));
    eqnphi = 
     uvar0[[All, i1]] (dx . phivar[[All, i]]) + 
      vvar0[[All, i1]] (dy . phivar[[All, i]]) - 
      1/Sc1 (dx2 + dy2) . phivar[[All, i]] - 
      Nt1/(Nb*Sc1) (dx2 + dy2) . Tvar[[All, i]];
    Tvar[[All, i + 1]] = Tvar[[All, i]] - dt1 eqnT;
    phivar[[All, i + 1]] = phivar[[All, i]] - dt1 eqnphi;
    Tvar[[left, i + 1]] = Tvar[[left1, i + 1]];
    phivar[[left, i + 1]] = phivar[[left1, i + 1]];
    Tvar[[top, i + 1]] = 0; Tvar[[bot, i + 1]] = 1;
    phivar[[bot, i + 1]] = 1;
    phivar[[top, i + 1]] = 0;, {i, tmax1 - 1}]; {T, phi} = 
    Map[Interpolation@Join[sgrid, Transpose@List@#, 2] &, 
     Partition[Join[Tvar[[All, tmax1]], phivar[[All, tmax1]]], 
      Length[sgrid]]]; -x0 (Derivative[1, 0][T][x0, y0] + 
      Derivative[0, 1][T][x0, y0])];
```

Test example

```
Nu[1, .5, 1, 0] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {2.32057, 0.221814}
```

Comment: @ Alex Trounev: Nice to see that you figured it out. The pressure field also looks a lot more reasonable. On my machine I get an additional time advantage of about 5.5swith the Method->"Banded" in LinearSolve. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @wvt_beginner Yes, you are right. Time decreases from 20.6789s to 18.6551s with `Method->"Banded"`. Maybe we also should add `Compile`, since `LinearSolve` is compliable function.

Comment: Well, to my knowledge `LinearSolve` is already highly optimized. By giving  it a try with `Compile`, i get a slowdown of approx. factor 5, with `CompilationTarget->"C"`. Maybe the biggest part of the slowdown is the fact, that - to my knowledge - one cannot use SparseArray objects inside `Compile`. When using  `LinearSolve[Normal@mat,(-1)*Normal@vec`] I get comparable timings here.

Comment: If compilation does not help, then the obvious way is to increase the integration time step. In the implicit scheme we used `dt=1/20`, and in the code above `dt=1/1000`. This  explicit scheme stable up to `dt= 1/500`. But code for `Nu` is unstably in this case.

Answer (score 5):

From the text it's not quite clear if you want to speed up the FEM solver or FDM solver or both. I am going to show you how the FEM solver should be written. The main reason that your FEM solver is slow, is that you manually use an iterative approach for the solver which it can do automatically quite well. Here is how you should write the FEM solver:

Here are the Navier-Stokes equations:

```
CFDModel = {
   Inactive[Div][-(\[Mu]*Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
      y}] + {u[x, y], v[x, y]} . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
    Derivative[1, 0][p][x, y], 
   Inactive[Div][-(\[Mu]*Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
      y}] + {u[x, y], v[x, y]} . Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}] + 
    Derivative[0, 1][p][x, y], 
   Derivative[0, 1][v][x, y] + Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y]};
```

Here is your source term:

```
source = {+(c1 + H1)*M1*u[x, y], c1*M1*v[x, y], 0};
```

And now, we solve it, same parameters, same mesh etc:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 {ufun, vfun, pfun} = 
  NDSolveValue[{CFDModel + source == {0, 0, 0} /. {\[Mu] -> 1, 
      M1 -> 5, H1 -> 0.1, c1 -> 0.5, 
      dt -> 1/20}, {DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, 
       x == 0 && y > 0], 
      DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == M1*x, v[x, y] == b1}, 
       y == 0 && x > 0.], 
      DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, y == L], 
      DirichletCondition[{p[x, y] == 0}, x == lb]} /. {L -> 1, 
      lb -> 5, M1 -> 5, b1 -> 3, dt -> 1/20}}, {u, v, p}, 
   Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {5, 1}]], 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}, 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0025}}];

(* {1.03448, Null} *)
```

This is more than a factor 10 speedup and this is the documented way for solving the NS-equations.

For completeness:

```
{ContourPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  Contours -> 20, PlotLabel -> "u", FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, ContourStyle -> Yellow],
  ContourPlot[vfun[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  Contours -> 20, PlotLabel -> "v", FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, ContourStyle -> Yellow]}
```

[image]

Now, you may argue that in some cases the approach I have shown here does not converge. Sure, that can happen if the nonlinearity is too strong. But even in that case the documented approach is preferable. And the reason is simple: The option "InitialSeeding" can be given to a parameterized version of the Navier-Stokes equations. Since it's not necessary here, I can't quite show it. However, in the upcoming version 14 there is a new tutorial on laminar flow modeling that shows this approach. In the mean time you can have a look at some hyperelastic material models that are very strongly nonlinear and where the same approach is used. Have a look [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/StructuralMechanics/Hyperelasticity.html#725517312). You can transfer that approach also to your parametric study.

In summary, simplifying the FEM solver give more that a factor of 10 speedup compared to your FEM solver (and even more compared to your FDM solver).

*Update 1:*

You have updated your question from a stationary to a transient version. I assume you are satisfied with the performance of the transient Navier-Stokes solver and I thus show the time integration of the second PDE you give:

```
mesh = xVel["ElementMesh"]

ClearAll[ic1, op1, bc1, T, phi]

ic1 = {T[-1, x, y] == 0, phi[-1, x, y] == 0};
bc1 = {DirichletCondition[{T[t, x, y] == 0, phi[t, x, y] == 0}, 
    y == height && x > 0], 
   DirichletCondition[{T[t, x, y] == sf[10  t + 5], 
     phi[t, x, y] == sf[10  t + 5]}, y == 0 && x > 0.]};
op1 = {
   Inactive[
      Div][({{-\[Mu]1, 0}, {0, -\[Mu]1}} . 
       Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + 
    D[T[t, x, y], t] + {{xVel[t, x, y], yVel[t, x, y]}} . 
     Inactive[Grad][
      T[t, x, y], {x, 
       y}] + ((Nb1*
        Grad[T[t, x, y], {x, y}] . Grad[phi[t, x, y], {x, y}]) + (Nt1*
        Grad[T[t, x, y], {x, y}] . Grad[T[t, x, y], {x, y}])), 
   Inactive[
      Div][({{-\[Mu]2, 0}, {0, -\[Mu]2}} . 
       Inactive[Grad][phi[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][({{-\[Mu]3, 0}, {0, -\[Mu]3}} . 
       Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + 
    D[phi[t, x, y], t] + {{xVel[t, x, y], yVel[t, x, y]}} . 
     Inactive[Grad][phi[t, x, y], {x, y}]};
Dynamic["time: " <> ToString[CForm[currentTime]]]
AbsoluteTiming[{T0, Phi} = 
   NDSolveValue[{op1 == {0, 0} /. {\[Mu]1 -> 1/Pr1, \[Mu]2 -> 
          1/Sc1, \[Mu]3 -> Nt1/(Nb1*Sc1)} /. rules /. {Sc1 -> 0.5, 
       Nt1 -> 0.5, Pr1 -> 1, Nb1 -> .5}, bc1 /. rules, ic1}, {T, 
     phi}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, {t, -1, 1}, 
    Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines"(*,
        "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"->True*)}}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = t;)];]
```

For me this time integrates in about 130 seconds. Almost a factor 20 faster than your version. Check if you need the "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions". I have said many times before you never, never, never need to specify `"InterpolationOrder" -> {T -> 2, phi -> 2}` when the requested interpolation order is the same, this is only useful if at least one of the requested interpolation orders differ. Also, there is no point in Inactivting a PDE and then calling Activate on it.

The one thing that is not ideal here is that I used:

```
((Nb1*Grad[T[t, x, y], {x, y}] . Grad[phi[t, x, y], {x, y}]) + (Nt1*
    Grad[T[t, x, y], {x, y}] . Grad[T[t, x, y], {x, y}]))
```

in place of the Inactive version. The reason is that the PDE parser stumbles over that; but the solution is not to activate the entire PDE but, rather, just that part. Have a look and see if this solution is what you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your approach to speed up FEM solver. But, your solution is valid for steady flow only, while my FEM solver designed for unsteady flow. Also I need to improve FDM solver.

Comment: @AlexTrounev same principal for unsteady flow.

Comment: Can you show FEM solver for unsteady flow?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, you mean like [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#643148355)?

Comment: Something like this, but unfortunately this approach is not working.

Comment: Please ask a new questions with the details.

Comment: Please, see Update 2 to my answer.

Comment: See update. Please check that it's correct.

Comment: (+1) Please, pay attention that your fast version takes 130s while my FEM version `Nu[1, .5, 1, 0]` takes 13.85s only :). Also please check that  there is no stationary version in my question. All my versions are transient with using implicit difference scheme with time step `dt=1/20`.

Comment: Unfortunately your version is not correct. It gives the Nusselt number  `-(Derivative[0, 1, 0][T0][1, 1, 0] + Derivative[0, 0, 1][T0][1, 1, 0])` of about 0.7 while the correct number is of about  0.23.

Comment: I suspect there is a difference because the flow has been ramped up and it seems that in your case you start from 0. You seem to use a fixed step dt for the time integration. How have you verified that your result is correct? Also, have you tried to solve the entire set of equations in one go?

Comment: Yes, you are right, that we used `UnitStep[t]` in a case of FDM and linear FEM, and `sf[t]` in a case of nonlinear FEM.  We can try to compare final flow at `t=1`. It is not efficient to solve the entire set of equations, since for parametric research we need equations for `T, phi` only. To verifier that result is correct we used data from the paper linked above.  In addition, we can compare FDM and FEM.